# Cannot select columns with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've coded the following snippet:

```
def connect_alchemy():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        connection (not showed for privacy reasons, take that Mark Zuckenberg (?)),
        echo = True
    )
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

    users = sqlalchemy.Table(
        'users', meta, 
        sqlalchemy.Column('username', sqlalchemy.String(32),
                           primary_key=True),
        sqlalchemy.Column('password', sqlalchemy.String(32)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('salt', sqlalchemy.String(255)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('role', sqlalchemy.String(32)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('last_login', sqlalchemy.DateTime),
        sqlalchemy.Column('first_name', sqlalchemy.String(32)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('last_name', sqlalchemy.String(32)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('email', sqlalchemy.String(64)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('phone', sqlalchemy.String(16)),
        sqlalchemy.Column('address', sqlalchemy.String(32)),
    )

    conn = engine.connect()
    meta.create_all(engine)

    q = users.select(users.c.username)
    res = conn.execute(q)
    print(res.all())

def main():
    connect_alchemy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which should list only the usernames of the table users, but SQLAlchemy (as I set echo=True) produces the following output:

```
2022-01-17 17:07:41,515 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2022-01-17 17:07:41,515 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-01-17 17:07:41,531 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2022-01-17 17:07:41,531 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00017s] ()
2022-01-17 17:07:41,537 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2022-01-17 17:07:41,537 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-01-17 17:07:41,553 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-01-17 17:07:41,553 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = %s AND table_name = %s
2022-01-17 17:07:41,553 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00026s] ('pharmacy', 'users')
2022-01-17 17:07:41,553 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2022-01-17 17:07:41,568 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.username, users.password, users.salt, users.`role`, users.last_login, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, users.phone, users.address
FROM users
WHERE users.username
2022-01-17 17:07:41,568 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00038s] ()
[]
```

It produces the query (what the hell with that 'WHERE'?):

```
SELECT users.username, users.password, users.salt, users.`role`, users.last_login, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, users.phone, users.address FROM users WHERE users.username
```

And I wanted:

```
SELECT users.username FROM users
```

If I execute a SELECT of all the table the result is correct, so I don't think that I have any problem regarding the creation of the connection.

Python version: 3.9.5

SQLAlchemy: 1.4.26

So the question is: I'm doing something wrong? Anyone has come across this? I tried to google it, but didn't find anything similar, sorry if it's repeated.

Comment: Try using `sqlalchemy.select(...)` instead of `users.select(...)`

Comment: "what the hell with that 'WHERE'?": https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I don't know where I read that I could do what I tried to do, so I didn't check documentation. Thanks again!